# Get directory path

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to get a certain file from inside my application. Now I came from a web development so I'm still not sure if what I'm doing is what correct. But I want to get the `Media` folder path and when I try to retrieve the image using

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Media\", "File.jpg")
```

It's returning a string of something like `c:/project/bin/Debug/Media/File.jpg` but my file is located in `c:/project/Media/File.jpg` how do I retrieve this? Or is the `bin/Debug` is the actual or correct location for the file if so how do I move it inside the `bin/Debug`? I would assume that rebuilding the project will move that image inside that `bin/Debug` but it didn't work.

I mean I still don't know how the actual project works specially when this is installed in a clients computer. Will all assets be located inside the `bin/Debug` folder? Is it a bad idea that my `Media` folder is located the same level as the `bin` folder?

Just to be clear can someone explain how does adding a media like images work and how it will be retrieved when it's installed or deployed in a clients computer? Should it retain the actual location (same location as the bin folder)? Or should I move the Media inside the Bin folder?

If I won't need to move that then how can I retrieve the file inside the Media folder my project directory looks like this

```
Project
  + bin
      + Debug        <-------- Get directory is looking inside this folder
          + Project.exe
          + Project.exe.config
          + Project.pdb
  + Media      <--------- I want it to look into this folder
      + File.jpg
```

Comment: Hi @JohnG ahh yes that's what I did sorry it's just a typo will revise my question

Comment: Is this file for a wpf-Control? Or what is the purpose?

Comment: @dba no I just need to add this image to the PDFSharp script that I build. So just attaching this image to the output pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is that you're more familiar with past MS build environments where the project folder is set as the current folder while the application is running, so you can access the source files directly. The WPF build process recreates the entire structure in bin as it will appear when installed, so you need to flag your data files to get copied into it as well.

In the file properties for the files in question (e.g. "File.jpg") set "Build Action" to "None" and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer"; this will cause them to be copied into bin as part of the build. Then all you have to do is this:

```
var folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var filename = $@"{folder}\Media\File.jpg";
```

Comment: Hi @Mark thanks for the reply. I just did what you suggested and then rebuild my project but I still don't see the Media folder inside the bin/Debug folder

Comment: You sure you've set those file properties properly? Try doing a clean and rebuild, this is definitely how you do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. I cleaned and then refresh my solution view and the Media folder is now part of the build. Thanks

Comment: In case you want the image file to be compiled into the output assembly, as a so-called *assembly resource*, set its Build Action to *Resource*, and Copy to Output Directory to *Do not copy*. Then load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris) like `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Media/File.jpg"))`. Thus you would avoid any external images files that could be replaced or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

- Record the install directory of the application into a registry key. This would be an absolute path, and you wouldn't need to locate the Media folder relative to `Environment.CurrentDirectory`
- Use [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) to set a relative variable dynamically:

  ```
   #if DEBUG 
      string MediaDir = "..\..\Media";
   #else
      string MediaDir = "Media";
  ```

  ... So that the correct path (relative to the location of `Environment.CurrentDirectory`) is set.

3. Embed the assets into the .exe as a resource and reference them using a [Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).
4. (Mark, I'm blatantly stealing yours) Reference the Media folder relative to the location of the exe, as given in Mark Feldman's answer. (+1 for you, Mark)

Answer (score -2):

Visualizing Mark's answer (sorry for german VS) :

[image]

and using code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( typeof(Program).Assembly.Location), "Media", "Smiley.jpg");
    }
  }
}
```

should work.
I personally prefer the type-Assembly over the Executingassembly for detect the path, since this ensures, that the location of the dll/exe from where the class is loaded will be reflected

Alternatively you may embed the image in your solution and refer to it directly as Bitmap:

[image]